# Highcharts how to save a selected legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I am trying to workout if it possible to get a callback from highcharts to say which legend item has been selected or de-selected. Which then I can add into my series data which gets saved, so when I load highcharts up again it has the saved selected legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [series.events.legendItemClick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick),

> legendItemClick: function
>
> Fires when the legend item belonging to the series is clicked. One parameter, event, is passed to the function. The default action is to toggle the visibility of the series. This can be prevented by returning false or calling event.preventDefault().

or [series.events.hide](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.hide) which gets called when a series is hidden.

> hide: function
>
> Fires when the series is hidden after chart generation time, either by clicking the legend item or by calling .hide().

With one of those in combination with [series.visible](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.visible) you should be able to do what you are after.

> visible: Boolean
>
> Set the initial visibility of the series.
>
> Defaults to true.

Comment: Great, now you just need to store this in some way. In a cookie, in a database, or some other creative way. There should be plenty of tutorials on getting/setting cookies. Such as [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)